# C argv pointer type

Tags: c++, c, pointers, argv

I'm confused as to how to use pointers to get this code to work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char* test = argv[1][0];
    printf("hello %s\n", test);
}
```

Here is the error:

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
  'char *' with an expression of type 'char'; take the address with &
  [-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: You have to use like `char* test = argv[1];`.`argv[1][0]` is type `char` and you have assigned it to `char *` which cause you issue.

Comment: For printing out a `char` you shall use `%c`. `%s` ist to print out a `0`-terminated `char` array aka "string".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of `argv[1][0]` is `char`.

The type of `argv[1]` is `char*`.

You need to use:

```
char* test = argv[1];
```

If you invoke your program with:

```
program "First Arguent" "Second Argument"
```

then, in `main`, `argc` is equal to `3`.

```
argv[0] = "program"
argv[1] = "First Arguent"
argv[2] = "Second Arguent"
argv[3] = NULL
```

Given such a case,

`argv[1][0]` evaluates to the first character of `argv[1]`, which is equal to `'F'`.

If that's what you would like to get, you can use:

```
char test = argv[1][0];
```

If you want to get the entire first argument, then you need to use:

```
char* test = argv[1];
```

Comment: It's usually worthwhile to consider the _meaning_ of expressions, not just their type. In this case, of course, the type helps to get you there. But since we're teaching, both should be explored.

Comment: This is excellent I was wanting to get the first char out of arv[1] so I was just using char* instead of char on accident. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks for helping to make the answer better.

Answer (score 6):

The first argument is `argv[1]`, and `argv[1][0]` is *the first character* of that argument. Change the code to

```
char* test = argv[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

char *argv[] is an array of pointers, and each pointer points to a character         array(null terminated).Suppose you pass "Hello World" as a command line argument to your program. The base   address of string (null terminated character array) is stored inside argv[1]. Since argv[1] points to a string, thus argv[1][0] gives the character at 0th
index in the string.

Now consider your assignment :

```
char* test = argv[1][0];
```

Here by using argv[1][0], you are actually indexing inside the string pointed to by the
argv[1], and assigning the charcater stored at 0th index of the string to the test
pointer. Since "test" is a pointer thus, it is bound to store address and not value.
The above assignment assigns a character value to test, and since the characters are
internally represented as integers in C, therefore you are getting a warning that says:

```
    incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
```

here the integer value refers to argv[1][0] and the pointer is test.

The above assignment can be used as :

```
char *test = &argv[1][0];   // assignment 1
```

which is equivalent to :

```
char *test = argv[1];   // assignment 2
```

as long as the index in the assignment 1 is 0.